# Prove that remainder of $\frac{(x-1)^t}{(x+1)^2}$ can be represented by a formula.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I suggest that any remainder of $\frac{(x-1)^t}{(x+1)^2}$ will be in form $$(-1)^{(t-1)}\cdot(2^{t-1}\cdot(tx+t-2))$$ for $$t>2$$. I found that by analysing remainders for small t. But how do I prove that?

Comment: Yeah, thank you for link, and thanks another sir for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to write
$$
(x-1)^t=(x+1)^2q(x)+ax+b
$$
If we substitute $-1$ to $x$, we get
$$
(-2)^t=-a+b
$$
If $t\ge1$, we can differentiate and get
$$
t(x-1)^{t-1}=2(x+1)q(x)+(x+1)^2q(x)+a
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Tottaly forgot that I could just diffirintiate here! $a=t(-2)^{(t-1)}$ , $b=(-2)^t+t(-2)^{(t-1)}$Thank you kind sir!